# PHP Search string for array of words

Tags: php

I am trying to make one PHP script which check un URL string for an match of any of the pointed words.

So here it is:

```
$yourWord='http://mywebsite.com/combo-points-carmaboy-boy';
$targets = array("kid", "kids", "boy", "six");

if (in_array($yourWord, $targets)) {
echo "FOUND!!";
}
else {
echo "NOT FOUND!";
}
```

In this case it's giving me result `NOT FOUND` but as you can see the word `boy` is contained in `combo-points-carmaboy-boy`.

So how i can make it found properly any of the target words in the string ?

Thanks!

Comment: Woah, woah, woah, you need to take a step back and review the [documentation for `in_array()`](http://us3.php.net/in_array). The string `http://mywebsite.com/combo-points-carmaboy-boy` certainly does not exist in `array("kid", "kids", "boy", "six");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$pattern = '/('.implode('|', $targets).')/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $yourWord, $matches)) {
  echo 'FOUND!!';
} else {
  echo 'NOT FOUND!';
}
```

**Edit:** Note that this will match the targets in the whole URL (including domain). If you only want to match the path, then you can parse the URL:

```
$path = parse_url($yourWord, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

You can then use this `$path` variable in `preg_match()`:

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $path, $matches)) {
```

**Edit 2:** The regex pattern above will match both `carmaboy` and `boy` in the URL. If you don't want that, you can use this pattern (it will only match `boy`):

```
$pattern = '/\b('.implode('|', $targets).')\b/';
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
$yourWord='http://mywebsite.com/combo-points-carmaboy-boy';
$targets = array("kid", "kids", "boy", "six");

foreach($targets as $target)
{
    if(preg_match("/" . $target . "/", $yourWord))
    {
        echo "Found target : " . $target . "<br/>" . PHP_EOL ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$yourWord is = **http://mywebsite.com/combo-points-carmaboy-boy** i think problems starting at here. Because you're looking **boy** word but you're int. is not boy. I think you can use array for $yourWord and then you can use codes again.

For ex. $yourWord = array ("http:/mywebsite.com/", "combo", "points", "carmaboy", "boy");